# why are the data types byte, char and short needed

Tags: java, jvm

I read in the JVM specification that the data types byte,short and char are internally treated as int.
So why having these data types if we don't have a benefit from their small size?

Comment: Mostly for arrays. An array of shorts still uses half as much memory as an array of integers of the same size.

Comment: I'm sure there is lot of algorithms depending on value ranges of  different integral types by, e.g., expecting integral value to overflow at certain point.

Comment: Apart from memory matters, these basic numeric types are often handy when handling communication protocols or code that interacts with compact structures which are defined outside of Java code. Of course, if the designers of the language really cared about this use case, they would have added unsigned types to the language so that we wouldn't need terrible tricks like `b & 0xFF` ...

Comment: Especially `byte` is of the utmost importance! Pretty much every data stream (files, network streams, ...) is represented by bytes in all major modern architectures (and pretty much all RFCs!) If Java had no easy way to represent that, it would be pretty hard to interoperate. Of course you *could* emulate a `byte[]` using an `int[]`, but the result would be either very memory inefficient or terribly complicated.

Comment: Using the smaller data types for variables will also take up less space within an instantiated object depending on byte packing boundaries and object overheads. Tailored correctly in a well known JVM, you can save considerable space on the heap even with more complex collections than an array. A 100 million records in memory that take up 40 bytes each might half your cloud hosting costs vs the same 100 million records taking up 160 bytes each. And yes, you might very well need all the records in memory at the same time. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In part it's for compatibility with C/C++, and in part it's to conserve memory - internally, a short is *stored* as a short, but it's *processed* as an integer.  A `new short[10]` takes up half as much memory as a `new int[10]`

Comment: +1: arrays, mostly. On the stack or in a local variable a `byte` takes up just as much room as an `int` (fields the JVM could optimize that, if it wished).

Answer (score 1):

It's for the gestion of the memory. Each variable has a memory space. The size of the space depends of the variable's type that you use.

Otherwise, the type char is very useful when you manipulate string. Indeed, you can have one character of the string using string.charAt(index)

Answer (score 1):

The answers given are very good, but I'll point out another possible use.  You can do some compile time checking of data types.  For instance, you can have an age (in years) of a person as a byte, and you can do compile time checking to make sure that a larger value stored in an int or short get used for that field.